# AJAX finish after my render() component - ReactJS - React-Router - JQuery -

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have next ReactJS component (It only render routes):

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            isAdmin: true,
            isAlumno: true,
            isProf: true
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.cambiarEstado();
    }

    cambiarEstado() {
        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://namey.muffinlabs.com/name.json?",
            data: "&with_surname=true&count=3&type=%22%22",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
        })
        .done((respuesta) => {
            //console.log(respuesta);
            this.setState({
                isAdmin: false,
                isAlumno: false,
                isProf: false
            })

        }).fail(function(respuesta){
            //console.log("¡Algo fué mal!");
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>

                <Route path="/" component={NotFound}/>
                <Redirect from="/alumno" to="/alumno/inicio"/>
                <Redirect from="/administrador" to="/administrador/inicio"/>

                <Route path="/" component={App}>

                    <Route path="alumno" component={AppAlumno}>
                        <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_Inicio, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_NuevaIncidencia, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="mis_incidencias" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_MisIncidencias, this.state)}/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="administrador" component={AppAdministrador}>
                        <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_Inicio, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="nueva_incidencia" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevaIncidencia, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="incidencias_recibidas" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_IncidenciasRecibidas, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="incidencias_recibidas/nuevo_informe" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevoInforme, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="informes" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_Informes, this.state)}/>
                        <Route path="informes/nueva_respuesta_informe/:id" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_NuevaRespuestaInforme, this.state)}/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/profesor/informes/nueva_respuesta_informe/:id" component={RequireProfesor(Profesor_NuevaRespuestaInforme, this.state)}/>

                </Route>

                <Route path="/:loggedAs/acceso_restringido" component={AccesoNoPermitido}/>
                <Route path='/404' component={NotFound} />

                <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />

            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I want do an AJAX, which changes the state of my component (this.cambiarEstado()), I receive next error: Error: Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be ignored.

The error is due to AJAX. Once loaded method render AJAX continue executing and when it finish try to change State. But it is not valid due to I pass state into method Render() in functions as (isAdministrador(), isAlumno(),...) so the state passed is the initial state, the new state received from AJAX does not exist, and I get that error. How could I solve this? (AJAX query finish earlier than method render, which allow me to pass correct states received from AJAX)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the state after `render` has run. I think your real problem is the use of `this` in `cambiarEstado`. Try putting the following line in your constructor:

```
this.cambiarEstado = this.cambiarEstado.bind(this);
```

But, I just noticed another problem. You are trying to define routes. You are not allowed to change routes once they have been defined. You can handle that by creating a `Loading` component and having your render method return that component instead of the routes until the ajax function has completed. After which, you can then have your render method return the routes. Something like this (some code deleted to simplify):

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            dataLoaded: false,
            isAdmin: true
        }

        this.cambiarEstado = this.cambiarEstado.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.cambiarEstado();
    }

    cambiarEstado() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://namey.muffinlabs.com/name.json?",
            data: "&with_surname=true&count=3&type=%22%22",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
        })
        .done((respuesta) => {
            this.setState({
                dataLoaded: true,
                isAdmin: false
            })
    }

    render() {

        if ( ! this.state.dataLoaded) {
          return (<div>Loading....</div>);
        }

        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>

                <Route path="/" component={NotFound}/>
                <Redirect from="/alumno" to="/alumno/inicio"/>
                <Redirect from="/administrador" to="/administrador/inicio"/>

                <Route path="/" component={App}>

                    <Route path="alumno" component={AppAlumno}>
                        <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAlumno(Alumno_Inicio, this.state)}/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="administrador" component={AppAdministrador}>
                        <Route path="inicio" component={RequireAdministrador(Administrador_Inicio, this.state)}/>
                    </Route>

                    <Route path="/profesor/informes/nueva_respuesta_informe/:id" component={RequireProfesor(Profesor_NuevaRespuestaInforme, this.state)}/>

                </Route>

            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it is not resolved. The error is as render() loads earlier than AJAX finish, then I pass into the functions the initial state, not the correct state. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example of you are saying? In your answer, please.

Comment: oh, ok! Thank you! I will try!.

Comment: Happy to help. Consider checking out React Router V4 when you get a chance. It takes a few hours to learn but it's a simpler api than previous versions.